# Run a Powershell Script from Workflow in SP Online

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online

I'd like to trigger a powershell script from a workflow. Is it possible?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SP Online workflows don't support code, so no, not directly. Though, you could create a web service and call it from workflow via the Call HTTP Service action.